# Getting Error- Could not initialize class weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionHelperImpl with weblogic-12.2.1.4.0

Tags: java, oracle, ejb, weblogic12c

I am facing issue with T3s connection to weblogic server with below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionHelperImpl
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at weblogic.transaction.TransactionHelper.getTransactionHelper(TransactionHelper.java:73)
at weblogic.common.internal.RMIBootServiceImpl_12214_WLStub.authenticate(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.RemoteAuthenticate$1.run(RemoteAuthenticate.java:67)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:386)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:163)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.RemoteAuthenticate.authenticate(RemoteAuthenticate.java:64)
at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.authenticateRemotely(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:927)
at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.pushSubject(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:857)
at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.newContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:609)
at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:418)
at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:353)
at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:322)
```

I am using wllfullclient jar and t3s connection to connect to WebLogic server.

I tried to search solution of above issue on oracle forums but didn't found any solution yet. can anyone guide me to correct place where I can search the solution of this issue or let me know If I need to add any other jar in class path.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

wllfullclient details

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Version: 12.2.1.4.0

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace to see the root cause of the NoClassDefFoundError ?

Comment: Hi @EmmanuelCollin / Thank you for response. I got the issue. Actually one of the JVM args that I was passing for WebLogic was not correct (wrong name) that's why it was giving me error while loading. I found that details in weblogic debug logs.